# How to pass variable from one file of JS to a query present in other file?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I am having 2 files present in my work index.js and post.js
the index.js file has the graphql query as below.

```
export const query = graphql`
 query IndexPageQuery($Limit: Int) {
  allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}, limit: $Limit) {
  totalCount`}}
```

The post.js has the return value as below:

```
return(          
  <div className={`all-posts ${this.props.featured ? 'featured' : ''}`}>
  <h3 className="sidebar-heading"> More Posts </h3> 
    {this.props.posts.map(({ node }) => (
    <div className="post" key={node.id}>
    <Link
        to={node.fields.slug}
        css={{ textDecoration: `none`, color: `inherit` }}
      >
      <div>
      <p>
        {node.frontmatter.title}{" "}
      </p>
      <span>— {node.frontmatter.date}</span>
      </div>
    </Link>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Now I am not able to pass the value to the variable Limit from post.js to index.js
Any solution how to do that??

Comment: If you using webpack, set the query variable global, like that `global.query = query;` hope this helps you

Comment: @JagjeetSingh

Nopes;

Actually, I am asking how I can set the value of the variable in post.js so that it gets rendered in the query present at index.js

Comment: @JagjeetSingh

like in the link here

[https://graphql.github.io/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/]

it has shown the rendering of variables in the same file but I need to access them from another file

Comment: You can use import in post.js file, like that `import index from './index.js'` and use `index.query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your query as an object attached to the global `window` object like this:

```
window['query'] = graphql`
  query IndexPageQuery($Limit: Int) {
  allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC}, limit: $Limit) {
  totalCount`}};
```

Then, ensure whichever file initialized this variable is loaded *before* any files that depend on your query variable. You'll be able to access it like so: `window.query`.

For example, if you define your query in `index.js`, ensure you load `index.js` before you load `post.js` or any other js file which depends on this query. (Not always necessary unless you have an IIFE but avoids any accidental undefined issues)

**Note:** The reason I'm defining your query on the window object likes this: `window['query'] = query` instead of `window.query = query` is because webpack won't alter the object key name. If you define it like `window.query = query` webpack will change the name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) ?

you can save data in key/value pair and read it anywhere you want .